# React Native Call Api

Tags: reactjs, native

```
"bank_account": Object {
      "name": "User Name",
      "account": "4916111323",
      "bank": "City Bank",
    },
```

here i can call

```
item.bank_account.name
item.bank_account.account
item.bank_account.bank
```

but here its not working

```
item.menu.image


"menu": Array [ Object {  
"image": "3",    
"item_id": "1",    
"price": "450"},   
],
```

should be something between menu and image because it object?

Comment: `item.menu` is an array of objects. So, `item.menu[0].image`. Or, for any other `index`: `item.menu[index].image`

Answer (score 1):

`item.menu` is `Array`. You need to access it's indexes: `item.menu[INDEX].image` (index is a zero-based index) e.g. `item.menu[0].image`